# Adding a video response to a form (preferably typeform)

Tags: html, forms, video

I would like to receive video responses to a form which is embedded on my website. At the moment I'm using Typeform but unfortunately they don't have an option for custom html inserts, so using addpipe.com won't work, unless I'm missing something obvious?

I've found workarounds using hidden fields via gravity forms or formsite (+ addpipe) however I'd much prefer to be able to do this with typeform as I like the service. They offer hidden fields, but I can't seem to get them to populate with the addpipe url like they do here: https://blog.addpipe.com/record-video-with-gravity-forms-and-pipe-video-recorder/

Thanks in advance

PS if anyone knows any Saas which offers what typeform does + video responses then please let me know!

Comment: if typeform supports a text field create an ajax response to upload a video maybe and then return the url link to the video in the text field?

Comment: You want people to upload a video to answer a question you ask on a typeform?
I think you can do it with typeform with File Upload question, but only on mobile https://www.typeform.com/help/file-upload-question/

Typeform also launched a new project, just to collect video answers, called VideoAsk, did you check it? https://videoask.it/

Comment: No text field available in Typeform unfortunately. Thanks Nicolas, but I want people to be able to record themselves as part of the response to my form, not just upload a file :( I did see videoask a few days ago, it looks great but at the moment is only available via iphone and has quite a few bugs still